# allauth providers not present in user details

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I am trying to setup SSO in my django project using Allauth which I have previously done, but for some reason my defined provider is not present in the user section to link the user to an external provider. This is the config:

```py
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = "myproject.users.adapters.AccountAdapter"
ACCOUNT_ALLOW_REGISTRATION = env.bool("DJANGO_ACCOUNT_ALLOW_REGISTRATION", True)
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = "username_email"
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "mandatory"
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_ON_GET = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False  # Username is not required
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True

SOCIALACCOUNT_AUTO_SIGNUP = True
SOCIALACCOUNT_EMAIL_AUTHENTICATION = True
SOCIALACCOUNT_EMAIL_AUTHENTICATION_AUTO_CONNECT = True
SOCIALACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'none'  # None because we trust azure

SOCIALACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_GET = True

SOCIALACCOUNT_ADAPTER = "myproject.users.adapters.SocialAccountAdapter"

OIDC_CLIENT_ID = env("DJANGO_SOCIALACCOUNT_OIDC_CLIENT_ID", default="")
OIDC_CLIENT_SECRET = env("DJANGO_SOCIALACCOUNT_OIDC_CLIENT_SECRET", default="")
OIDC_CLIENT_URL = env("DJANGO_SOCIALACCOUNT_OIDC_CLIENT_URL", default="")

SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    "openid_connect": {
        "APPS": [
            {
                "provider_id": "keycloak",
                "name": "Keycloak SSO",
                "client_id": OIDC_CLIENT_ID,
                "secret": OIDC_CLIENT_SECRET,
                "settings": {
                    "server_url": OIDC_CLIENT_URL,
                },
            }
        ]
    }
}

MIDDLEWARE += ["allauth.account.middleware.AccountMiddleware"]
```

And the errorlog
[image]